# How to apply Marshall Palmer function at ID level in R?

Tags: r, physics

I'm analyzing Dual-Polarization radar data and I want to add the result of the [Marshall Palmer](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Marshall-palmer_relation) relation as an ID-level variable in [my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mo7cqyalx52yyjq/train.csv?dl=0).

There's no CRAN function for this that I can find, but another R user has script wherein he applies the relation as an estimate of an expected value in the data:

```
# From Troy W. (thanks!)
# A few small changes by hack-r

## Someone better in R than me could probably clean up/refactor the code a bit.


library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

test <- fread('../input/test.csv')


mpalmer <- function(ref, minutes_past) {

  # order reflectivity values and minutes_past
  sort_min_index = order(minutes_past)
  minutes_past <- minutes_past[sort_min_index]
  ref <- ref[sort_min_index]

  # calculate the length of time for which each reflectivity value is valid
  valid_time <- rep(0, length(minutes_past))
  valid_time[1] <- minutes_past[1]
  if (length(valid_time) > 1) {
    for (i in seq(2, length(minutes_past))) {
      valid_time[i] <- minutes_past[i] - minutes_past[i-1]
    }
    valid_time[length(valid_time)] = valid_time[length(valid_time)] + 60 - sum(valid_time)
  } else {
    # if only 1 observation, make it valid for the entire hour
    valid_time <- 60
  }

  valid_time = valid_time / 60

  # calculate hourly rain rates using marshall-palmer weighted by valid times
  sum <- 0
  for (i in seq(length(ref))) {
    if (!is.na(ref[i])) {
      mmperhr <- ((10^(ref[i]/10))/200) ^ 0.625
      sum <- sum + mmperhr * valid_time[i]
    }
  }

  return(sum)

}
results <- test %>% group_by(Id) %>% summarize(Expected=sum)
write.csv(results, file='sample_solution.csv', row.names=FALSE)
```

In addition to being incredibly slow with Big Data, the problem with the code above is that it doesn't create a column of results within the original data, which would allow it to be productionalized in an ETL pipeline that created this relation at the ID level as 1 predictive variable in the dataset.

I tried rewriting the function like this:

```
mpalmer <- function(ref, minutes_past) {
  # Credit to Troy for this
  # edits by Jason Miller, hack-r.com

  # order reflectivity values and minutes_past
  sort_min_index = order(minutes_past)
  minutes_past <- minutes_past[sort_min_index]
  ref <- ref[sort_min_index]

  # calculate the length of time for which each reflectivity value is valid
  valid_time <- rep(0, length(minutes_past))
  valid_time[1] <- minutes_past[1]
  if (length(valid_time) > 1) {
    for (i in seq(2, length(minutes_past))) {
      valid_time[i] <- minutes_past[i] - minutes_past[i-1]
    }
    valid_time[length(valid_time)] = valid_time[length(valid_time)] + 60 - sum(valid_time)
  } else {
    # if only 1 observation, make it valid for the entire hour
    valid_time <- 60
  }

  valid_time = valid_time / 60

  # calculate hourly rain rates using marshall-palmer weighted by valid times
  sum <- 0
  for (i in seq(length(ref))) {
    if (!is.na(ref[i])) {
      mmperhr <- ((10^(ref[i]/10))/200) ^ 0.625
      sum <- sum + mmperhr * valid_time[i]
    }
  }

  return(sum)

}
```

and then applying it like this:

`train.samp$mp   <- aggregate(train.samp$Ref, by=list(train.samp$Id), FUN = mpalmer, minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past)`

which I think mostly works, however after running for a long time, it returned an error like this:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "mp", value = list(Group.1 = c(10L,  : 
  replacement has 9765 rows, data has 10000
```

I've tried it on different samples of the data and the error message is always in that format, though the specific numbers may change. There's no missing data in the dataset.

Any idea how to fix this function (and/or make it faster)?

*Update: I've got it working with a for loop but it is **SO** slow...*

Comment: One quick fix: replace the `for` loop with `valid_time[i] <- minutes_past[i] - minutes_past[i-1]` with valid_time[2:length(minutes_past)] = diff(minutes_past)`.

Comment: @Gregor I verified that worked and it sped up the analysis by about 3% - 4% on a large test dataset. Thanks for that!

Comment: Also looks like the last `sum` calculation could be vectorized, maybe `sum = sum(((10^(ref/10))/200) ^ 0.625 * valid_time,  na.rm = T)` instead of the `for` loop?

Comment: @Gregor Good idea. I will explore that after work today and see if I can get rid of that `for` loop. If you want to post another version of the function with your improvement then I'd be happy to mark it as the solution since you're the only one helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm going with for now, but I'm still open to other solutions.

Basically, I went back to the original function then broke apart the overly large dataset into manageable chunks and ran for loops on each chunk:

```
  train.samp      <- train.samp[order(train.samp$Id),]
  train.samp1     <- train.samp1[order(train.samp1$Id),]

  train.samp.id    <- unique(train.samp$Id)
  train.samp.id.1  <- train.samp.id[1:25000]
  train.samp.id.2  <- train.samp.id[25001:50000]
  train.samp.id.3  <- train.samp.id[50001:75000]
  train.samp.id.4  <- train.samp.id[75001:100000]
  train.samp.id.6  <- train.samp.id[100001:125000]
  train.samp.id.5  <- train.samp.id[125001:150000]
  train.samp.id.7  <- train.samp.id[150001:175000]
  train.samp.id.8  <- train.samp.id[175001:200000]
  train.samp.id.9  <- train.samp.id[200001:length(train.samp.id)]

  train.samp.1 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.1,]
  train.samp.2 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.2,]
  train.samp.3 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.3,]
  train.samp.4 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.4,]
  train.samp.5 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.5,]
  train.samp.6 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.6,]
  train.samp.7 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.7,]
  train.samp.8 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.8,]
  train.samp.9 <- train.samp[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.9,]

  system.time(
  for(i in unique(train.samp.1$Id)){
    train.samp.1$mp[train.samp.1$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp.1$Ref[train.samp.1$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp.1$minutes_past[train.samp.1$Id == i])
  }    )
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.2])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.3])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.4])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.5])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.6])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.7])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.8])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    
  for(i in unique(train.samp$Id[train.samp$Id %in% train.samp.id.9])){
    train.samp$mp[train.samp$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp$Ref[train.samp$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp$minutes_past[train.samp$Id == i])
  }    

system.time(  
  for(i in unique(train.samp1$Id)){
    train.samp1$mp[train.samp1$Id == i] <- mpalmer(train.samp1$Ref[train.samp1$Id == i], minutes_past = train.samp1$minutes_past[train.samp1$Id == i])
  }
```

The function is not shown here, but I am about to take advantage of @Gregor's suggestion in the comment.